# Multiple group_concat ordering one of them wrong order of the others

Tags: sql, group-by, group-concat

i have 3 columns a, b and c.
I need as output:

- a
- b as group_concat
- c as group_concat (order ASC)

I can do a order by inside of the group_concat but the issue is that the order of b is not correct order for c them.

I never had that situation so i dont now how i can solve that.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
select a, group_concat(b order by c), group_concat(c order by c)
from t
group by a;
```

Comment: It is, thanks.
I guess it was to easy to figure it out :P